# Error reading images through the directory

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

This is the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gmood/Desktop/SP1/TestSP1v2.py", line 26, in <module>
   load_images('C:/Users/gmood/Desktop/SP1/', 10, 4, 2, 5, 'paying-attentionPT1.png')
 File "C:/Users/gmood/Desktop/SP1/TestSP1v2.py", line 19, in load_images
   img = extract_face(path)
 File "C:/Users/gmood/Desktop/SP1/TestSP1v2.py", line 9, in extract_face
   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4) 
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\\a\\opencv-python\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\objdetect\\src\\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

Sample code provided with the assignment:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
from numpy import asarray   
from os import listdir
import cv2 as cv  
face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')  

def extract_face(filename): 
    image = cv.imread(filename) 
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image ,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)  
    \# Draw the rectangle around each face  
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  
    cv.rectangle(image,(x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)  
    return image  
   
def load_images(directory, x_size, y_size, row, col, outp_fn):  
    plt.figure(figsize=(x_size, y_size))  
    i = 0;  
    for filename in listdir(directory):  
        path = directory + filename 
        img = extract_face(path)  
        b_channel, g_channel, r_channel = cv.split(img)  
        img_RGB = cv.merge((r_channel, g_channel, b_channel)) 
        plt.subplot(row,col,i+1),plt.inshow( img_RGB ) 
        plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])  
        i = i + 1
        plt.savefig(outp_fn, format='png', dpi=150)

load_images('C:/Users/gmood/Desktop/SP1/', 10, 4, 2, 5, 'paying-attentionPT1.png')
```

Comment: Are there some files in `C:/Users/gmood/Desktop/SP1/` that aren't images?

Comment: Just make sure you are able to read in the path correctly, print out the filename variable. Error says images it reads are empty, which happens usually when the path is incorrect. (For formatting your code in SO use the Code sample option (Ctrl+K) in options toolbar).

Comment: yes some are other python test files @JohnGordon

Comment: Use condition like this to make sure you only pass 'PNG' filepaths to cv2.imread() function: if file.endswith(".png")

Comment: Then that's likely the problem.  You're passing some non-image files into `extract_face()`.  Inside that function `imread()` correctly returns a null result, and then you try to pass that null image result into other functions that aren't expecting it.